# node.js- post requests to endpoint begin to get stuck after a while

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, mongoose, amazon-sns, node-request

I've developed a node.js webapp with express+mongoose deployed to an Amazon EC2 instance.

The app receives SNS notifications when a file is uploaded to a specific s3 bucket, stores something in mongodb and then makes an https post to some endpoint outside amazon.   https post is done in this way using requests library:

```
 var options = {
        url:"https://"+config.get('some.endpoint')+"/somepath",
        method:'POST',
        body:postdata,
        json:true
    };


    requests.post(options,function(err,response,body){
        if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
          logger.info("notified ok ");
        }else{
            logger.error("1 " + err);
            logger.error("2 " + response);
            logger.error("3 " + body);
        }
    });
```

This was done using a simple callback model ( i.e I didn't use async library).

Files are uploaded continously so the SNS hits my app at the same rate ( ~5/10 requests per second). The first ten minutes of the app being up, I can see ( via checking logs) that http post are being delivered in a near speed as incoming requests arrive.

But at some point, the requests.post callback starts falling behind until it stops showing up in the log file,(despite requests keep coming).  I can tell, by checking the  other endpoint (the one specified in config.get('some.endpoint')) , effectively, that posts aren't being delivered. In different bursts and with great delays ( 5 min or more) , some new messages appear in the log, like if it was trying to catch up,  but in the long term they stop showing up at all.

I've realized that if I make some manual flow-control by stopping/restarting the incoming  requests I can make it work ok.

Am I doing something wrong? are requests getting stacked up somewhere because of some reason? How can I check this? Should I use some library to ensure execution?

Could it be that node.js prefers to process new incoming requests vs processing old requests callback and somehow these callbacks are never executed?

Any help or suggestion on how I can debug this issue is welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding `pool: false` to your `options` and see if that helps. I've encountered issues with this before when using the http agent.

Comment: did not help actually, same status. I've been told that one should use promises or some framework like async to handle callbacks correctly. I've made some tests and seem to work better.